# Selenium no such element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the meeting minutes from the website below. I keep receiving an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="dlAgendaView"]"}
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Replace with appropriate WebDriver for your browser

# Navigate to the website
url = "https://oprs.co.monmouth.nj.us/oprs/Meetings/AgendaFrmHolder.aspx?eid=1129&ty=1"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Find the iframe element
iframe_element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")

# Switch to the iframe context
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)

# Find the element with ID "dlAgendaView" within the iframe
agenda_view_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "dlAgendaView")

# Extract and print the inner HTML of the element
agenda_view_html = agenda_view_element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(agenda_view_html)

# Switch back to the default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The content is "hidden" under two `<iframe>`s. To load the `#AgendaView` element you can use this example (using only `requests`/`BeautifulSoup`):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://oprs.co.monmouth.nj.us/oprs/Meetings/AgendaFrmHolder.aspx?eid=1129&ty=1"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
iframe_url = "https://oprs.co.monmouth.nj.us/oprs/Meetings/" + soup.iframe['src']
iframe_url = iframe_url.replace("AgendaFrame.htm", "AgendaLhs.aspx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(iframe_url).content, 'html.parser')

# print sample text:
t = soup.select_one('#dlAgendaView').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
print(t)
```

Prints:

```
1 . Director Calls Meeting to Order 2 . Pledge of Allegiance 3 . Statement Re:  Open Public Meetings Act 4 . Proclamations a . Proclaiming the month of May as Apraxia Awareness Month - Director Arnone (in house) b . Proclaiming May as Military Appreciation Month - Director Arnone (in house) c . Honoring Nathaniel Attardi, awarded the BSA Heroism Award for life saving activities - Deputy Commissioner DiRocco (in house) d . Honoring our Law Enforcement Officers in recognition of National Police Week - Commissioner Kiley (in house) e . Honoring our Correctional Officers in recognition of National Correctional Officers Week - Com

...
```